# Which would have a lower bandwidth cost - HTML5 or FLV?

Tags: video, flash, flv, html5

Recently YouTube and Vimeo added HTML5 players to their websites, with options to use them rather than the FLV video. I understand that HTML5 video is less CPU intensive, but what about bandwidth? So...

**Given the same video on YouTube/Vimeo which format would be "cheaper" to view: HTML5 or FLV?**

Comment: FLV is a container, not a codec, and you can't embed FLV files directly in websites anyway. Maybe you're asking Flash vs HTML5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither, it's totally dependant on the codec used, just as flash is. I believe they stream in the same format, though they don't have to.

Answer (score 4):

YouTube and Vimeo both use the H.264 codec for video, be it displayed via Flash or HTML5. You're downloading the same file either way - the only thing changing is the application that's playing that file